# features.h: No such file or directory (MinGW on Linux Multiarch)

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm working on configuring CodeBlocks to compile Windows binaries on my Linux machine. I've been working on meticulously setting up all of the project build options, and I know I'm getting close.

Here's my problem: When compiling my code for Windows x86 (32-bit), I am receiving the following error, in short:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/timeb.h:21:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
 #include <features.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

I think this might be linked to my use of `<ctime>`, but I'm not 100% positive on that.

Here is my full, verbose build output.

```
-------------- Clean: DebugWin32 in infiltrator (compiler: MinGW)---------------

Cleaned "infiltrator - DebugWin32"

-------------- Build: DebugWin32 in infiltrator (compiler: MinGW)---------------

i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -Wall -g -m32 -pthread -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/mirclient -I/usr/include/mircommon -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -v -DWINVER=0x0400 -D__WIN95__ -D__GNUWIN32__ -DSTRICT -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -D__WINDOWS__ -DWINVER=0x0400 -D__WIN95__ -D__GNUWIN32__ -DSTRICT -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -D__WINDOWS__ -Iinclude -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -c /home/jason/Code/Repositories/infiltrator-git/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/Winx86/main.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir='/usr/lib/gcc-mingw-w64' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --enable-lto --with-plugin-ld --enable-threads=win32 --program-suffix=-win32 --program-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-as=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c++11' '-Wall' '-g' '-m32' '-pthread' '-I' '/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include' '-I' '/usr/include/atkmm-1.6' '-I' '/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print' '-I' '/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include' '-I' '/usr/include/giomm-2.4' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include' '-I' '/usr/include/pangomm-1.4' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include' '-I' '/usr/include/glibmm-2.4' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include' '-I' '/usr/include/gtk-3.0' '-I' '/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0' '-I' '/usr/include/at-spi-2.0' '-I' '/usr/include/dbus-1.0' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include' '-I' '/usr/include/gtk-3.0' '-I' '/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/' '-I' '/usr/include/mirclient' '-I' '/usr/include/mircommon' '-I' '/usr/include/cairo' '-I' '/usr/include/pango-1.0' '-I' '/usr/include/harfbuzz' '-I' '/usr/include/pango-1.0' '-I' '/usr/include/atk-1.0' '-I' '/usr/include/cairo' '-I' '/usr/include/cairomm-1.0' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include' '-I' '/usr/include/cairo' '-I' '/usr/include/pixman-1' '-I' '/usr/include/freetype2' '-I' '/usr/include/libpng12' '-I' '/usr/include/sigc++-2.0' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include' '-I' '/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0' '-I' '/usr/include/libpng12' '-I' '/usr/include/glib-2.0' '-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include' '-I' '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu' '-v' '-D' 'WINVER=0x0400' '-D' '__WIN95__' '-D' '__GNUWIN32__' '-D' 'STRICT' '-D' 'HAVE_W32API_H' '-D' '__WXMSW__' '-D' '__WINDOWS__' '-D' 'WINVER=0x0400' '-D' '__WIN95__' '-D' '__GNUWIN32__' '-D' 'STRICT' '-D' 'HAVE_W32API_H' '-D' '__WXMSW__' '-D' '__WINDOWS__' '-I' 'include' '-I' '/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include' '-I' '/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include' '-c' '-o' 'obj/Debug/Winx86/main.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -I /usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I /usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I /usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -I /usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -I /usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -I /usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I /usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I /usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I /usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I /usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I /usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I /usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I /usr/include/mirclient -I /usr/include/mircommon -I /usr/include/cairo -I /usr/include/pango-1.0 -I /usr/include/harfbuzz -I /usr/include/pango-1.0 -I /usr/include/atk-1.0 -I /usr/include/cairo -I /usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include -I /usr/include/cairo -I /usr/include/pixman-1 -I /usr/include/freetype2 -I /usr/include/libpng12 -I /usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I /usr/include/libpng12 -I /usr/include/glib-2.0 -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I include -I /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include -I /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -D_REENTRANT -U_REENTRANT -D WINVER=0x0400 -D __WIN95__ -D __GNUWIN32__ -D STRICT -D HAVE_W32API_H -D __WXMSW__ -D __WINDOWS__ -D WINVER=0x0400 -D __WIN95__ -D __GNUWIN32__ -D STRICT -D HAVE_W32API_H -D __WXMSW__ -D __WINDOWS__ /home/jason/Code/Repositories/infiltrator-git/main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -m32 -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase-strip obj/Debug/Winx86/main.o -g -Wall -std=c++11 -version -o /tmp/ccOBvz2u.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 (i686-w64-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2-p11, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/sys-include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/gtk-3.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/pango-1.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/cairo"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/cairo"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/libpng12"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/gtkmm-3.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include
 /usr/include/atkmm-1.6
 /usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print
 /usr/include/gdkmm-3.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include
 /usr/include/giomm-2.4
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include
 /usr/include/pangomm-1.4
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include
 /usr/include/glibmm-2.4
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include
 /usr/include/gtk-3.0
 /usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0
 /usr/include/at-spi-2.0
 /usr/include/dbus-1.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include
 /usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/
 /usr/include/mirclient
 /usr/include/mircommon
 /usr/include/cairo
 /usr/include/pango-1.0
 /usr/include/harfbuzz
 /usr/include/atk-1.0
 /usr/include/cairomm-1.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include
 /usr/include/pixman-1
 /usr/include/freetype2
 /usr/include/libpng12
 /usr/include/sigc++-2.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include
 /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
 /usr/include/glib-2.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 include
 /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include/c++/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/include-fixed
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 (i686-w64-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2-p11, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: bef7442156978b65409b2327e910d16a
In file included from /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/time.h:277:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/thread.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:87,
                 from /home/jason/Code/Repositories/infiltrator-git/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/timeb.h:21:22: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
 #include <features.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

**Specs:** Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit, C++, CodeBlocks 13.12, MinGW
I'm using gtkmm in this project as well.

**How do I fix this and get the code compiling?**

Comment: Have you cross compiled all the supporting libraries you're using with mingw as well (such as gtkmm and all its dependencies ?)

Comment: You know, that occurred to be briefly, but I would have no idea how to do that. I installed via synaptic, and I try to minimize what I build from source, as it is so easy to mess up one's system that way. Any advice?

Comment: Your code is including `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/timeb.h` which is not a valid file if you're trying to compile for Windows.

Comment: You're currently pointing the compiler to header files intended for linux with all the `-I' '/usr/lib/x86_64` , `-I/usr/include/cairo` and so on, and that's not going to work. You need to configure and build all the libraries you're using for mingw as well. A rather big task.

Comment: Not a simple task, but theoretically doable? Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this, be it a tutorial, documentation, or something? I can't find squat. >.>

Comment: @JonathanWakely, how do I get it pointing to the Windows versions of those? I *assume* they're built into MinGW, but this is all quite new to me.

Comment: No, they're not built in to MinGW, no more than those other headers are built in to GCC. You need to install versions of those libraries that are built with MinGW.

Comment: I was getting confused between my import of `time.h`, which IS built into MinGW as part of the standard C library, and glibmm's use of `time.h`. Still fighting with building glibmm with mingw.

Comment: Okay, I have the Windows binaries of gtkmm (which require a volcano sacrifice of a technician to get, I might add), and I added those to all the Compiler and Linker paths (both for the MinGW compiler settings and the project settings), but it STILL tries to use the ones in the /usr/lib. Any advice? This is going on three weeks.

Comment: @CodeMouse92, I encounter the same issue like you. Did you solve this? If yes, how?