# MinGW compilation says header files are missing, which package maybe missing?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, mingw, gcc-warning

This is the first gcc error on compilation, copying features.h from the web into the include folder for MinGW helped :

```
$ gcc -g hello_world.c
In file included from c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:55,
                 from hello_world.c:1:
c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:174:10: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
 #include <features.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

This is the new error :

```
$ gcc -g hello_world.c
In file included from c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:174,
                 from c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:55,
                 from hello_world.c:1:
c:\mingw\include\features.h:406:10: fatal error: stdc-predef.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdc-predef.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The hello-world file :

```
#include <stdio.h>   int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) { 

           /* I am C developer */ 

           printf("Hello, Poftut! \n"); 

           return ;  }
```

C:\MinGW\bin\ is in PATH.Pretty sure I have missed some package installation.

Comment: try with `#include <sys/features.h>` in case (no `sys/` under Linux, but may be needed for cygwin ?). What is your version of _gcc_ ? Also better to add a newline after the lines with include

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291704/features-h-no-such-file-or-directory-mingw-on-linux-multiarch ?

Comment: gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3) 8.2.0 . The sys folder doesnt seem to have a stdc-predef.h; this is on windows.

Comment: under Debian the path is `/usr/include/stdc-predef.h`, and about _features.h_ ?